# React Native「react-native run-ios」実行時に「Cannot find entry file」が出てしまう

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

上記サイトを参考にしつつ、「react-native run-ios」を実行した段階で以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots:["/User/xxxxx/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager"]
```

どうすれば改善できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ルートディレクトリで`npm start`を実行しながら、`react-native run-ios`を実行するとうまくいきました。